# How to count duplicates in a vector (C++)

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I was working through an exercise in C++ Primer. Actually, I refined my first version. Problem is I not only want to detect duplications in a vector, but also how many times they were duplicated. I'm having trouble with the latter.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {

vector<int> nums{1,3,1,5,7,8,9,7};

sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());

for(unsigned int i = 0; i != nums.size(); ++i){
if(nums[i] == nums[i + 1]){
    cout << nums[i] << " is a duplicated number" << endl;
    }
}



return 0;

}
```

EDIT: Also just noticed my logic is flawed. If a number appears more than twice it will print out multiple times it's a duplicate. Which is redundant.

Comment: If it finds the same duplicate several times in a row, that is how you know the number of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, here is my suggested solution:

[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4b27597efc7b51c)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {

vector<int> nums{1,3,1,5,7,8,9,7};

sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());

for(auto it = std::cbegin(nums); it != std::cend(nums); ) {  

    int dups = std::count(it, std::cend(nums), *it);
    if ( dups > 1 )
        cout << *it << " is a duplicated number, times: " << dups << endl;
    for(auto last = *it;*++it == last;);
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Tested this one and it says every value is duplicated even if it isn't. Even if a number only appears once it says it was duplicated 1 time which isn't correct. Not being rude just thought you should know.

Comment: @Matt fixed it.

Comment: @matt I have rewritten this sample using slightly less advances c++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/450e2cb42622383b

Comment: thanks appreciate that you wrote a stripped down version. Still trying to wrap my head around some of it. I'm determined to learn C++ but it's not coming that fast to me like maybe some of you :(.. Been at it for about a month

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    map<int, int> duplicate;
    vector<int> nums{1,3,1,5,7,8,9,7,1};
    vector<int> nums_sorted{nums};
    sort(begin(nums_sorted), end(nums_sorted));

    auto beg = begin(nums_sorted) + 1;
    for (;beg != end(nums_sorted); ++beg) {
        if (*beg == *(beg - 1)) {
            duplicate[*beg]++;
        }
    }

    for (const auto& i : duplicate)
        cout << i.first << " appear " << i.second+1 << " times" << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
1 appear 3 times
7 appear 2 times
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm newer to C++. Even after reading the reference I don't know what a map is. Also why did you add + 1 at the end of the beg declaration? I removed it to test and it works same. Just wondering.

Comment: @Matt to start comparing at index 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can pair up `std::unique<>()` with `std::distance<>()`:

```
std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
auto unique_end = std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end());
std::cout << std::distance(nums.begin(), unique_end);
```

Answer (score 0):

A stupid but quick solution:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums{1,3,1,5,7,8,9,7,1};
    std::map<int, int> dups;
    for(int i : nums)
        ++dups[i];
    for(auto& dup : dups)
        cout << "Number " << dup.first << " has " << dup.second - 1 << " duplicates\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't know what map is

Comment: Why do you say this is stupid? Do you have a reason?

Comment: By stupid (I think) I meant "simple", it just seems to me to be the most straightforward way to solve the problem. Using unordered map would be more efficient though. Sorting and counting duplicates in a sorted array would be more memory efficient as well.